# Why is my query running so slowly when returning values from another table in Access?

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, query-optimization

I am running a rather simple query in MS Access.  I am attempting to filter results from a table using a WHERE clause.  My statement is as follows:

```
SELECT DATA.*
FROM DATA
WHERE DATA.Account_Number In (
    SELECT Lookup.AccNum 
    FROM Lookup
);
```

I have noticed this query is extremely slow to execute.

Conversely, if I name the account numbers explicitly, the result is returned in a fraction of the time.

```
SELECT DATA.*
FROM DATA
WHERE DATA.Account_Number In ("00001","00002","00003","00004","00005");
```

The second query takes mere seconds, while the first - given the same number of accounts in a table format - takes several minutes.

Comment: How many records exist in `Lookup`?

Comment: The table contains only 1 field with 5 records.  It makes it easy to dump a list of accounts from Excel without having to format them within quotes and comma-delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to use `Lookup` to filter `DATA`.  You can accomplish that by joining the two tables.

Create an index on `Lookup.AccNum` if it's not already indexed.

```sql
SELECT d.*
FROM
    DATA AS d
    INNER JOIN Lookup AS l
    ON d.Account_Number = l.AccNum;
```

Comment: Please let us know if `Account_Number` and `AccNum` are not both text datatype.

Comment: confirmed.  AccNum is Integer, whereas Account_Number is Text.  Also, for future reference, I'm curious as to why my original post was edited.

Comment: If possible, make both fields the same datatype so Access won't need to perform a datatype conversion for join or `IN ()` comparison.

Comment: Regarding the edit, see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm not too familiar with that concept in Access and general databasing.  Is there a way I can cast, like I would a variable, in SQL?  Or, would this be required to be changed in the schema?  Also, thanks for the clarification regarding the edit.  Wait, is that allowed?  Just kidding. ;)

Comment: I meant change the field's datatype in table design. If a permanent change is not possible/practical, you can explicitly cast the datatype in the query ... perhaps `ON CInt(d.Account_Number) = l.AccNum`. However, then I think Access' query designer will not be able to represent the join in Design View, which may not be a concern for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks Hans!  Any idea why using sub-queries is so inefficient in Access?  Is this inherent to most databases, and just happens to be a noticeable performance hit in Access?  Or, will most databases tolerate sub-queries well, with Access being an anomaly?  I'm interested from the theoretical perspective.

Comment: I think a critical factor is whether the db engine is able to use indexed retrieval.  Often with joins and indexed fields, it can.  But with `IN ()`, it may not be able to.  Sorry, I don't know enough to say anything more useful about those low-level details.  But I think that applies to databases in general, not just Access. BTW, try adding an index on `DATA.Account_Number` if it's not already indexed and see whether that has a noticeable performance impact.

Comment: The results I provided, i.e. minutes, already considers that `Account_Number` is indexed.  I fear how much time would elapse if it was not indexed.  That is an interesting point, where an `IN()` query could prevent you from leveraging performance advantages associated with indexed fields.  I will keep that in mind.  Access isn't a very robust engine as far as I can tell.  I should likely migrate this data to MS SQL Server or Postgres, but I really like the datasheet view provided in Access as a front-end.

Comment: Hold the phone!  Your Access db can use ODBC links to tables and views in PostGreSql or SQL Server; I've used both.  And you can open the linked objects directly in Datasheet View or use them as data source for Access forms and reports.  So you can combine Access' convenient RAD goodness with a more capable data store.  It's slick.

Comment: I did that with MySQL at one point, but kept having issues with the differences in data types that Access doesn't recognize.  Also, had some massive problems with queries not flowing through correctly.  Are you saying that things work a lot better with Postgres or SQL Server?  Also, are you aware of a better front-end software?

Comment: I haven't had much trouble due to datatype incompatibility.  But mostly I started with Access tables, then used ODBC to transfer them to the servers. And I haven't done it with MySQL so can't say whether Postgres and SQL Server are easier.  Re front-end I don't know of anything which can compete with Access' RAD capability.  That's the reason I still use Access ... even though I despised VBA when I first encountered it.  You're welcome to email me if you want to discuss this further.